# MissingMethodException when accessing global media type formatters from an AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to access the first configured media type formatter from within the `OnAuthorization()` method of a custom `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` that I am writing. However, when I access the "Formatters" property of the configuration, I am getting a `MissingMethodException`.

**Doesn't work:**

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Perform authentication.
    if (authenticationFailed)
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<MyReturnType>(new MyReturnType(), actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.First())
        };
}
```

throws System.MissingMethodException - Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_Formatters()'.

**Works:**

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Perform authentication.
    if (authenticationFailed)
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<MyReturnType>(new MyReturnType(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
        };
}
```

However, because this attribute is defined in a library that is being used across several projects, and some of the projects use XML instead of JSON for their "default" media type converter, I can't use the second approach that works since I don't know what format to return the data in.

Replacing `actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.First()` with `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.First()` also results in the exception.

I am using this same method of accessing the "default" media type formatter in a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` without any problems, why would this not also work in an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`?

Does anyone know how to access the configured media type formatters from an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`?

Note: I realize that I could have a way of specifying the media type formatter to use as part of the attribute initialization, but I was hoping that I would not have to do that and that I could just simply access the configured media type formatters. That and I am very curious as to why this isn't working.

Note 2: The version of the System.Web.Http DLL in use is 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, turned out there was an assembly binding missing in the config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```